# Why won't the Excel process close while app is running

Tags: excel, vb.net, memory-management, winforms-interop

**Question: Why won't the Excel process close while app is running?** Please don't jump the gun and mark it duplicate. If you could show the change needed in the code I really appreciate it. **Excel process closes nicely when I close the app**. I researched this problem for last few day read several SO posts and tried several things but nothing is working except for calling process.kill which I prefer to avoid if possible.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim misValue As Object
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Try
            ''EXCEL CREATION/INITAILIAZATION
            misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
            If xlApp Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!")
                xlApp = Nothing
            End If
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)


            ''WRITE TO WORKSHEET
            xlWorkSheet = TryCast(xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "THIS"
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "IS"
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "A"
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 4) = "TEST"

            ''FORCEFULLY CAUSING ERROR, NOW THE EXCEL PROCESS HANGING IN TASK MANAGER 
            ''xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, -1) = "ERROR LINE"

            ''SAVE WORKSHEET
            Dim Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", "_")
            Dim Dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Output\" & Name & "Output.xls"
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
            xlWorkBook.CheckCompatibility = False
            xlWorkBook.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Dir, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, _
                                Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            xlWorkBook.Close(False)
            xlApp.Quit()

            misValue = Nothing

            If Not IsNothing(xlWorkSheet) And System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.IsComObject(xlWorkSheet) Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
                xlWorkSheet = Nothing
            End If

            If Not IsNothing(xlWorkBook) And System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.IsComObject(xlWorkBook) Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
                xlWorkBook = Nothing
            End If

            If Not IsNothing(xlApp) And System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.IsComObject(xlApp) Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp)
                xlApp = Nothing
            End If

            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim exMsg = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but if you can, I would suggest you find a good API to save excel files. With the interop you can get problems like this and it's very slow.

Comment: What is your problem? You clearly bold *Excel process closes nicely when I close the app* which counters your question. Also, not too familiar with VB.Net, but you should be releasing resources (`xlApp = Nothing`) in the `Catch` or better yet in the [`Finally`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) clause

Comment: @Parfait Problem is the first bold statement. If the object is declared in a sub then at the end of the sub it should go out of scope. To make this more clear if you run the above code and click the button few times you will notice all excel process instance except for one will close at the end of the sub.

Comment: @the_lotus - One such library is [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus) which is available through NuGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is double dot reference in .net. Read here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx

so once you deconstruct

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
```

as

```
xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Add(misValue)
```

and then release it, you are all good.

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call doSomeWork()
    GC.Collect()
End Sub

Private Sub doSomeWork()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks '// Added new variable to avoid double dot.
    Dim misValue As Object
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Try
        ''EXCEL CREATION/INITAILIAZATION
        misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        If xlApp Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!")
            xlApp = Nothing
        End If
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
        xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Add(misValue)


        ''WRITE TO WORKSHEET
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)

        'xlWorkSheet = TryCast(sheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "THIS"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "IS"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "A"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 4) = "TEST"

        ''FORCEFULLY CAUSING ERROR, NOW THE EXCEL PROCESS HANGING IN TASK MANAGER 
        ''xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, -1) = "ERROR LINE"

        ''SAVE WORKSHEET
        Dim Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", "_")
        Dim Dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Output\" & Name & "Output.xls"
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBook.CheckCompatibility = False
        xlWorkBook.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\temp\a.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, _
                            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        xlWorkBook.Close(False)
        xlApp.Quit()

        misValue = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried with xlWorkbooks as separate variable to avoid the chaining dots but that had not worked, so when I saw your answer working, I really had to figure out why it did not work for me previously and went after all the delta between my solution and yours. Turns out TRY/CATCH block was the culprit. Commented out the try/catch block and my original code up above works. Thanks for the motivation your post gave me.

Comment: If you were to add try/catch block to this solution it will fail..atleast It did for me and tested on coworkers box also...No clue why that happens

Comment: hmm.... from event handler calling a separate sub which does all the work  , will allow you to use try catch blocking. Call the sub and then clean. updated code works for me.